# How to define an object with n properties in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi

Im using swagger with OpenApi 3 and my API returns the following object:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "username":true,
        "gender":true,
        "age":true
    },
    "pictures": {
        "1234":true,
        "1235":false
    },
}
```

But not all fields are required, so this is valid too

```
{
 'fields':{
   username:true
 }
}
```

The picture`s keys (1234 and 1235) are ids, so they are dynamic.

How can I define this kind of schema?

Comment: Are the field names fixed or is `fields` a hashmap/dictionary?

Comment: I think its a hashmap

Comment: I added more info